# Custom Class subclass of SKEmitterNode not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, enums, sprite-kit

Im writting a Simple SpriteKit game , but I have got a really serious error.
I created a Subclass of SKEmitterNode which i Named GameNode. I need it for some special instance methods. I set a property for this Custom Class(GameNode). Its the following:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) nodetype GNodeType;
```

Yes, i ussing an enum for this property type. My enum is the following:

```
    typedef enum {
    nodetypeblue,
    nodetypered,
    nodetypegreen,
    nodetypewhite

}nodetype;
```

Ok , now what is my problem. When I instance this class with the following custom init method:

```
-(id)initWithRandomTypeforSkScene:(SKScene*)Scene{
    self=[super init];
    if (self) {
        nodetype type = arc4random_uniform(4);
        self.GNodeType=type;
        NSString *bluepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bluenode" ofType:@"sks"];

        NSString *pathtoadd = [NSString string];


            switch (type) {
                case nodetypeblue:
                    pathtoadd = bluepath;
                    break;
               //I have some possiblilies here i not list them all, its desnt matter
                default:
                    pathtoadd = bluepath;
                    break;
            }

            self = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:pathtoadd];
            self.position = CGPointMake(arc4random_uniform(Scene.size.width-40)+20, arc4random_uniform(Scene.size.height-40)+20);
            //self.name = @"node";
            [self setScale:0.25f];



        return  self;

    }
    else{
    return nil;
    }

}
```

OK, after that, I try to create az instance of this class like this:

```
GameNode * Node = [[GameNode alloc] initWithRandomTypeforSkScene:self];
//Self is a SKScene here
```

And here is my problem. This is returning a SKEmitterNode not a GameNode. How I know this? Because whenever i call for the Node.GNodeType the xcode send an Exception with the following error message:

> -[SKEmitterNode GNodeType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10a022f80

Im setted lot of brakepoints and tried that i can, but it didnt solved anything. 
Oh and after I create this instance called "Node" I checked, that right after creation the tpye is a SKEmitterNode not GameNode. If i check the type or the GnodeType inside my class everything is OK. I have problems just outside after the creating,initialization.Help please.

Comment: archived emitters are of type SKEmitterNode, no way around that. Moreover you replace self with the unarchived object, voiding anything you did to self before that. You should probably not subclass the emitter, but SKNode that contains a emitter node.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it tomorow.

Comment: Thanks it's woriking now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With help of LearnCocos2D i succesfully solved the issue.

SO I created a Property for my class which holds an SKEmitterNode. I added the sks to the property and i presented this Property instead of the whole class.